# Dropwizard Hibernate @UnitOfWork for nested transactions without manual session handling

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, dropwizard, unit-of-work

I have a Dropwizard service which uses dropwizard-hibernate for DB calls. Currently, we are using `@UnitOfWork` on top of resource methods for achieving transactionality.

However, we recently have the use-case of committing some part of the code inside the resource methods into transactions.

I've tried using `UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory` and putting method level annotations of UnitOfWork inside the methods of my resource method. However, the problem with this is that those DB calls that are not wrapped in `@UnitOfWork` do not have access to any session and hence fail.

As a workaround, I've tried putting the `@UnitOfWork` annotation in a nested fashion (on the resource method as well as on internal methods). However, my internal methods are not writing the transaction to DB after they exit the scope. Instead, one final transaction gets committed when the resource methods return.

I've also tried setting the 'transactional' property to false for the top level `@UnitOfWork` annotation, but to no benefit.

I do not want to manually handle sessions inside my Dao classes since other callers of these classes are using `@UnitOfWork` annotation at the resource level.

Any idea how this can be achieved?